# QML dependency/reuseability (static code) checker

Tags: qt, dependencies, qml, qtquick2, reusability

For the sake of writing re-useable QML code I am looking for a (static code) checker which can detect unwanted dependencies across different qml files.

To give an example where B.qml depends on identifiers from A.qml:

**A.qml**

```
Item {
    id: dependencyId
    ...
    delegate: B {}
}
```

**B.qml**

```
Item {
    id: delegateB
    ...
    text: dependencyId.text
}
```

As the text element of B.qml depends on a identifier from A.qml, this code cannot be reused properly.

As long as the id of Item in A.qml won't change, this code would compile/run, and thus the dependency will not be noticed.
I tried *QmlLint*, but this gives no errors.

Are there static code checkers for QML available which can check this?

Comment: You can use `qmlscene` on each file. If there is such a dependency, it will raise a `ReferenceError`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (to accomplish with qmllint), thank you!
Added the --quit option, to incorporate it in my build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a custom build step in the sourceDirectory running qmlscene for each *.qml file, filtering results only on "reference" errors.

Thanks [derM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586077/qml-dependency-reuseability-static-code-checker/41588005#comment70376686_41586077) for the tip on using qmlscene.

**Command:** find

**Arguments:** . -name '*.qml' -exec qmlscene --quit {} \; 2>&1 | grep -rnis 'reference'

**Working directory:** %{sourceDir}

Screenshot:
[image]

*(2>&1 is needed to parse stderr, which is where the error messages are being displayed)*